# AVAudioPlayer. Optional redirect of audio files. In _audio i am getting null

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I have debug this code in url I am getting the "fileName" string, which i want. But in _audio i am getting null.

I am using an AVAudioPlayer to play and stream audio files. I am playing audio files from resources and document directory, but if they are absent in document directory then I want to play that specific audio from it's url. By streaming and buffering it. Here is my code:

```
NSString *fileName = @"http://ilm.coeus-solutions.de/frontend/images/audios/mp3test.mp3";
fileName = [fileName stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:fileName];
AVAudioPlayer *_audio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
```

Comment: have you tried collecting error? Create nsError object and post what is the error. and make sure the sound present on that url.

Comment: Yes! I have copy that url and play into browser, that playing audio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slam dear! Please read again my question I have just asked about audio streaming rather than downloading it and then playing it.

This below link helped me. By the way thanks all who try to help me.

```
http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code,

```
NSData *filelocation=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ilm.coeus-solutions.de/frontend/images/audios/mp3test.mp3"]];

MyAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithData:filelocation error:nil];
```

hope this will solve your problem